# Connection between Routes, Static Pages Controller, and View in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

New programmer here. I'm going through Hartl's tutorial for Rails. Whenever you add a new page you first edit the routes file in config/routes.rb. Then you add an action to the Static Pages controller and finally you add the view (this one is obvious). Can someone please explain the relationship between routes and the action for the Static Pages controller? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

action name in the controller calls the view page with the same name for example. 
If you have a controller named admin inside the controller folder
the controller has an action named, index

now when you send a get request to the URL `localhost:3000/admin/index` it will call the index action from admin controller after completing the action the view page will be displayed remember the view page named index has to be inside the folder.

```
views --> admin --> index.html.erb
```

now , calling the action index by hitting the url

```
localhost:3000/admin/index
```

will raise an error " no routes found for url "

for this you have to provide the permission in the config/routes.rb file

```
get "admin/index"
```

now you can access the url

if you dont want to go to default page with the same name as the action as default behavior , then simply redirect to the view page you want .